# How to use Yield in my linked list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing some Homework and the question is: Write a Python Generator that walks through the nodes of a linked list.

Hint: Use yield.

```
class Node:
      pass

def my_generator():

start = Node()
point = start

point.data = 1
print(point.data)
point.next = Node()
point = point.next

point.data = 2
print(point.data)
point.next = Node()
point = point.next

point.data = 3
print(point.data)
point.next = Node()
point = point.next

point.data = 4
print(point.data)
point.next = None
```

I'm relatively new to Python, and I've spent the last 2 days trying to figure out how to use Yield in this piece of code.I understand I could do this way easier by using other options in Python but this is the set question for my homework. Thank you

Comment: You might want to reformat your code. The whitespace got lost in the copy-paste, so it's unclear what your code does.

Comment: Thanks, just edited it now.

Comment: First, your class won't run.  The pass needs to be indented.  The code that follows seems to just be creating a linked list 1 -> 2 -> 3 ->4 -> None, but your question seems to ask how to write code that would walk through a linked list, not create one.

Comment: First of all it does run. Secondly, that's exactly what my code is supposed to do, creating a linked list that goes 1>2>3>4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a [look](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) at the basic shape of a generator might help:

```
def firstn(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
        yield num
        num += 1
```

which we can just call and use in something taking an iterable, for example,

```
sum(firstn(50))
```

Your list seems to give me `next` and returns `None` when it's done, so you need

```
def my_generator():
    item = start
    while item is not None:
        yield num
        item = item.next
```

Decide if this is being a class member or not - I'll leave that up to you. I also haven't added code for the list itself. 
Your current "generator" appears to be setting the data as it walks through - try to keep one function to populate the list, so you can make the generator just do one thing - walk the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using yield to generate an iterator of your list:

[What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)